# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget using TabBarView inside DraggableScrolledScheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, draggable, tabbar, flutter-widget

**What I want to achieve**

I tried to create a sticky TabBar using StickyHeader plugin inside DraggableScrollSheet.
I try to achieve scrolling like this.

[image]

**The Problem**

But everytime I scrolled, there is "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget." error.

I have tried to move the TabBar (wrapped by Container) and TabBarView (wrapped by Expanded) outside the StickyHeader and wrapped it with Column, but it doesn't works.

**This is my minimal code**

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: redMain,
        ),
      ),
      DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.82,
        minChildSize: 0.82,
        builder: (BuildContext context, myScrollController) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: ListView(
                      controller:
                          myScrollController, // assign controller here
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 34)),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 8),
                                  child: Text('Featured', style: Title1),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                  height: 100,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            StickyHeader(
                              header: Container(
                                margin:
                                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 22, bottom: 22),
                                child: TabBar(
                                  controller: _tabController,
                                  labelColor: Colors.red,
                                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                                  tabs: [
                                    Tab(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "All",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Tab(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "News",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              content: Container(
                                height: 2000,
                                child: Expanded(
                                  child: TabBarView(
                                    controller: _tabController,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        width: double.infinity,
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        height: height,
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width: double.infinity,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        height: height,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I wrap Expanded with Container and give it "dummy" fixed height because if I only use Expanded, error occured. But actually what I want is infinite scrolling without fixed height.

```
  content: Container(
             height: 2000,
             child: Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                   controller: _tabController,
                    children: <Widget>[
                     Column(
```

**The question**
How to get rid of "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."? And how to make TabBarView infinity scroll without fixed height?

Comment: Can you include full widget of [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hey thankyou for answering my question, I'm sorry for the late responds. Please check my edited question. Thanks!

Comment: I think bellow answer solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

**`use Positioned widget inside Stack widget`**

Comment: I tried wrapping the Container and DraggableScrollSheet each with Positioned, wrapping only the Container with Positioned, and wrapping only the DraggableScrollSheet with positioned, but it seems nothing is working, I still get the "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget." error.